# cant reset text in div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

this should be an easy answer, i havent done any js in a while

i have a submit button and a  div in my html :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
<div name="result">result here </div>
```

When the submit button is clicked i want to change the text in the div  my code looks thus:

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function(){   
  $('div[name=result]').val('results from database ')   //set new text   
});
```

an anyone point out why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you sure the submit is not submitting and refreshing the page? Maybe replace it with a regular button? `<input type='button' />` or `return false` maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[name=submit]').click(function(){   
  $('#result').text('results from database ')   //set new text   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    <div id="result">result here </div>
```

Comment: Welcome Lucy :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change name attribute to class in div.

```
<div class="result">result here </div>
```

Then, use `text` method to set value in non-input elements. `text` should be used only when the value is pure text ( no HTML elements );

```
$('div.result').text('results from database');
```

If your results from database contains HTML, use `html` method

```
$('div.result').html('results from database');
```

*[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ekcjLeqm/3/)*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ID for the div instead of name. Like below:

```
<div id="result">result here </div>
```

Now you can change the value by ID like:

```
$('#result').val('results from database ');
```

Answer (score 0):

div elements should not have a `name` attribute. You should use an `id` attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
<div id="result">result here </div>
```

then javascript/jQuery, notice the `.html` for the div, you could also use `.text()`. you have `.val()` for you div element, `.val()` only works on input elements and it gets or sets the `value` attribute.

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function(){   
  $('#result').html('results from database ')   //set new text   
});
```

Also, I would suggest to use an `id` attribute for the button, unlees you were wanting to possibly select multiple buttons that share the same `name` attribute value becuse `name` does NOT have to be unique, but `id` does. So if you just want that one specific button, you should use the `id` attribute and selector.

Answer (score 0):

eaay way is use class or ID to show result

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
<div class="result">result here </div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('input[name=submit]').on('click', function (){
      $('.result').html('results from database');
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
<div id="result">result here </div>

  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('input[name=submit]').on('click', function (){
      $('#result').html('results from database');
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you write your html like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
<div data-name="result">result here </div>
```

and then use below script to change text of your div:

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function(){   
    $('div[data-name="result"]').text('results from database ')   //set new text   
    return false;    // For not submitting the form so that 
                     // you can see the changes if in case 
                     // page is getting submitted it won't submit
});
```

In your code you made two mistakes due to which it was not working.
You div selector was missing quotes around result and val should i.e $('div[name=result]').val("") should be replaced with $('div[name="result"]').text("").

val is replaced with text due to the fact that val is used for form elements which have their default value attribute which is used to send values to server upon submission.

Also on should avoid using name attribute for normal dom elements other than form elements. In place of them you can define custom attribute like "data-name".

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function(){   
  $('div[name=result]').text('results from database ')   //set new text   
});
```

Comment: Have you ever tried name attribute to div ? If no, try once, you will get it

Comment: However i agree with you with div name isn't appropriate